# Dynamic stored procedure faster on second use

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Dynamic stored procedure returns data in 30 seconds first time but same procedure with same or different parameters returns in 2-5 seconds on second use.

web(asp.net) site.

Main table has more then 250 Million rows and logical partitioning policy has been applied on it.

Comment: Parameter sniffing/Caching.Let me guess: parameter is datetime range or custom made search query involving many fields and wildcards?

Comment: Please post your stored procedure.

Comment: Parameters are Date and varchar type.Is it due to database caching?
If it is database caching then why it is responding fast when I change parameter?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly** vendor-specific

Comment: Its for SQL Server 2008 r2 server.

Comment: Queries are suppose to be faster when run again as SQL Server caches the execution plan, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx . Is your question "why is my original query taking 30 seconds, because that's not fast enough?"